# How to get value form record in sencha touch

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2, sencha-touch-2.1

I am trying to get value from nested json, but unable to get value. I have following data structure.
Here I am printing record.

[image]

What i did.

```
 onWordTap: function(view, index, target, record, event) {
        var wordName=record.get('name');
        console.log("Word--->>>>"+wordName);
        console.log(record);
    },
```

but i get in console like this:-> `Word--->>>>undefined`

I have tried this also:

> **var wordName=record.data.get('name');**

but getting

> **Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'get'**

my JSON looks like this: [JSON](http://alucio.com.np/trunk/dev/sillydic/admin/api/word/my_favourite_words_with_definition/SDSILLYTOKEN/650773253e7f157a93c53d47a866204dedc7c363)

My previous question is also related to this type question, please watch . [Previous Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18371402/unable-setting-nested-json-data-on-localstorage-in-sencha-touch)

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming this is a `DataView` or a `List`, and that `onWordTap` is a listener for for `itemtap`.

If that is the case, to get data from records, you just need `record.get('name')`.  You can also use `record.get('definitions')[0].definition` (note that you've spelled it `defintion` in your code - beware).

Comment: @ Kevhender, i too have same problem when i use record.get('name') it consoles undefined.

Comment: can you shed some light how can i make it dynamic?

Comment: when i am using record.get('')[].definition it's giving Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Comment: @sur007, I would have to see your code to diagnose anything.  You should probably post a new question.

Comment: Can you look onto this,  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18125596/pass-argument-from-tpl-sencha

Comment: Can you please please look on this i have watched http://www.kevhender.net/desktop/index.html this on mobile when orientation changes it doesnot restarts but my app restart can you please shed some light on it. I would be so thankful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18372136/sencha-app-restarts-on-orientation-change

Comment: Sorry @sur007, I've never had any problems with orientation changes, and I've never done anything special to address the issue...

Comment: @ kevhender, it's ok. i think it's only problem when making android app not on web app. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

your JSON contains array of data , so you need to access it with index. you can do it like this.

```
var wordName = record.data[0].get('name');
```

Comment: This is wrong.if one name only i have get already like this: record.data.data[0].name; but i have multiple word and definition, in that time what can i do. any way thank you for your reply.

Comment: you can always loop it and get the value dude. you will get the length from the array , just put a loop on it and fetch the 'name'

Comment: thank you for reply, in loop it does not work. How to find which id holder word you have going to click.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have a data property inside the data object. So it means sencha recognize the record as it has only one field actually called data. So, if im not wrong, what's the output of:

```
console.log(record.get('data'));
```

Also, please add the model associated to the store containing `record`.

Comment: console.log(record.get('data')); gives ---undefined--- output. I have not understand.but you can see my full model,store, view and controller associated question.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18371402/unable-setting-nested-json-data-on-localstorage-in-sencha-touch

Comment: your answer sounds quite reasonable. console.log(record.get('data')); consoles undefined whereas console.log(record.data); consoles class of record as shown above in question and if we console.log(record.get(record.data.data)) it consoles data:Array[1] can be seen in above image.Thank You.

Comment: @Nico Grunfeld Can you please take look onto this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18125596/pass-argument-from-tpl-sencha